# OAuthWebSecurity, MVC! Can you force the user to log in each time?

Tags: oauth

I am using the code that gets implemented in a new MVC Project for user to Log into Google,Yahoo, Etc.. I have it all working but what I notice is when I try to log-in with Yahoo, there might be another user (my brother-in-law) logged into Yahoo on my machine, so when I try to log-in, it tries to register him. That is annoying, so I want it to force the user to re-enter their username/password on Yahoo (google, etc). Is that possible? This seems like a security flaw also. If I was in my app and then logged out, but did not log out of Yahoo, Google,etc.. anyone could come along and log in to my app. That hole is so wide and obvious it tells me I am probably doing something wrong, because they would not have designed it that way. I am thinking I need to destroy some cookie or token on my site when the sessions ends or I log out..

Comment: I don't think you can force them to logout of a completely different website.  If someone leaves themselves logged in on a public/shared computer, the security hole is the user.  There's no session or cookie owned by your ASP.NET MVC application that manages this.  Indeed, the whole _point_ of this implementation is so that your application _can't_ manage the authentication from the provider.

Comment: Consider this.I am logged out of Yahoo and my app. I then log into my app which forces me to log into yahoo (that is fine). I then log out of my app and walk away from the computer. Another person sits down at the computer and they can log into my app without any credentials because I am still logged into yahoo. I realize I should log-out of my yahoo account, but you would think my app (or yahoo actually) would say even though you are logged into  yahoo, I am still going to make you put in your credentials to get into my site.. Am I crazy? Is that how it works? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `"make you put in your credentials to get into my site"` - That's precisely against the point of the implementation.  Your site doesn't require credentials.  It doesn't need them.  In fact, it doesn't *want* them.  If nobody ever types a password into your site, you're not responsible for their passwords.  Which is a very good thing.  What you're describing is definitely a scenario that users need to be aware of.  I suggest that you put information on your site about how such a login system works.  Maybe a reminder to logout of Yahoo!.  But, ultimately, your app doesn't handle authentication.

Comment: Keep in mind that this implementation isn't _necessary_.  As "cool" as things like OAuth and OpenID are, if the implementation doesn't fit the users and use cases of your application then it shouldn't be used.  If it makes more sense to use a username and password on your site, then use that instead of OAuth.  If both make sense, use both and let the user select which they want.  Provide information and links to more information on the login page so users can be informed on that decision.

Comment: When I say "make you put in your credentials to get into my site", I should have said re-direct you back to the yahoo log-in to put in your credentials (even though you might be already logged into yahoo). Sigh.. I appreciate your helping me, after talking to some other people they say that is just how it is supposed to work. Thank for the time you spent helping!

Comment: Well, I tried this very scenario with StackOverflow and it logged me right in because I was already logged into yahoo. So I guess that is how it is supposed to work

Comment: `"re-direct you back to the yahoo log-in"` - That's exactly what happens.  The thing is, you're already logged in to Yahoo so Yahoo immediately redirects you back.  The actual authentication is between the user and Yahoo.  By using OAuth, your app is basically saying, "Hey man, I don't want your password.  That's between you and Yahoo, or whoever.  If Yahoo says you're somebody, then I'm going to assume you're that somebody."  Admittedly, I've never thought of the use case you're talking about.  Mostly because I don't really use shared computers.

Comment: Thanks David, I appreciate you commenting.

Comment: Maccurt, I am running into the same situation with my site.  I am using facebook as my oauth provider.  Right on there site they discuss an option to force users to reauthenticate.  Haven't found a way to get this to work through the .net library though.  I don't think your use case is invalid at all.  See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication/